# Trying to get mvc resources to serve my static resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing locally using both jetty and tomcat.

My images, css, javascript files are in:

```
/src/main/webapp/assets
```

where the folder assets has:

```
/src/main/webapp//assets/images
/src/main/webapp//assets/css
/src/main/webapp//assets/images/
```

My spring config file has:

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/" />
```

I'm confused as to what both mapping and location mean?

I think mapping means that that spring will only try and serve the static files if it has the url with the pattern like:

```
www.example.com/assets/
```

What does location do?

My html currently has:

```
src="/assets/images/logo.gif"
```

I've tried playing with the location value, and I don't get to render the image for some reason.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Have you read point 16.14.5 in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your project structure has `/src/main/webapp/assets/images`, then you want to use:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
```

and then in your JSP reference files as

```
src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/images/logo.gif"
```

Its more common to have a project structure like `/src/main/webapp/images|css|js` and then use:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/" />
```

but still keeping URLs as `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/images/logo.gif`

Comment: contextPath is what?  because I wanted to keep the images relative if possible.  Or even have a subdomain for the urls (say they are served from a CDN....

Comment: contextPath is the root path (usually app/war name) if you are running in tomcat, etc (but can be empty if running with virtual host in production environment). How are you running your app - what is the full URL to a page?

Comment: well it might be a custom mapped domain (will have thousands of them) or a subdomain on say mywebsite.example.com

Comment: contextPath simply lets you run the app on dev machine via tomat like `http://localhost:8080/appname/assets/images/bar.jpg` and also works when deployed in prod env like `http://foo.com/assets/images/bar.jpg` - just like `<c:url..>`